# Cleaner way to initialize AQI parameter matrix

Tags: r, matrix

I'm making a basic excercise in R where the goal is to calculate the AQI for each air pollutant. I'm initializing AQI matrix with the parameters provided at https://www.epa.gov/sites/production/files/2014-05/documents/zell-aqi.pdf using cbind. I just want to know if there's is a cleaner way to do this procedure?

```
AQI <- as.matrix(c(0,50,51,100,101,150,151,200,201,300,301,400,501,500),nrow=14,ncol=8)
AQI <- cbind(AQI,c(0.000,0.054,0.055,0.070,0.071,0.085,0.086,0.105,0.106,0.200,0,0,0,0))
AQI <- cbind(AQI,c(0,0,0,0,0.125,0.164,0.165,0.204,0.205,0.404,0.405,0.504,0.505,0.604))
AQI <- cbind(AQI,c(0.0,15.4,15.5,35.4,35.5,54.4,54.5,150.4,150.5,250.4,250.5,350.4,350.5,500.4))
AQI <- cbind(AQI,c(0,54,55,125,126,254,255,354,355,424,425,504,505,604))
AQI <- cbind(AQI,c(0,4.4,4.5,9.4,9.5,12.4,12.5,15.4,15.5,30.4,30.5,40.4,40.5,50.4))
AQI <- cbind(AQI,c(0,35,36,75,76,185,186,304,305,604,605,804,805,1004))
AQI <- cbind(AQI,c(0,53,54,100,101,360,361,649,650,1249,1250,1649,1650,2049))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cbind` returns a matrix, so you can "simply" write

```
AQI <- cbind(c(0,50,51,100,101,150,151,200,201,300,301,400,501,500),
             c(0.000,0.054,0.055,0.070,0.071,0.085,0.086,0.105,0.106,0.200,0,0,0,0),
             c(0,0,0,0,0.125,0.164,0.165,0.204,0.205,0.404,0.405,0.504,0.505,0.604),
             c(0.0,15.4,15.5,35.4,35.5,54.4,54.5,150.4,150.5,250.4,250.5,350.4,350.5,500.4), 
             c(0,54,55,125,126,254,255,354,355,424,425,504,505,604), 
             c(0,4.4,4.5,9.4,9.5,12.4,12.5,15.4,15.5,30.4,30.5,40.4,40.5,50.4),
             c(0,35,36,75,76,185,186,304,305,604,605,804,805,1004),
             c(0,53,54,100,101,360,361,649,650,1249,1250,1649,1650,2049))
```